# Can two columns with multiple elements be created without containers or JS?

Tags: html, css

I have two columns of divs, that I want to display like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5g5YU/3/).

```
<div id="cont">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="d1">1left</div>
        <div id="d3">3left</div>
        <div id="d5">5left</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="d4">4right</div>
        <div id="d2">2right</div>
        <div id="d6">6right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, for purposes of creating a responsive design I don't want to use containers, and I would prefer to not use JS for basic formatting purposes.

The problem with this, is that simply floating containers left and right creates "rows," as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5g5YU/) (3left is pushed right due to the increased size of 1left).

Is it possible to create columns of multiple `div`s without using containers or JS, and if so, how?

Comment: While this is an interesting question and I would like to see the possible answers to it, I have to ask why not use containers?

Comment: @Nate Responsive design. If I don't use containers, the `div`s can mix into a single column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is my attempt:**

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 185px;
    clear:both;
}
.right {
    margin-left:185px;
}
```

Basically, whatever `width` you set for `.left`, use that for `margin-left` in `.right`. This way you don't have to use the `float` property on both the `div`.

**UPDATE #1**

In `.left`, add:

```
clear:both;
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AL6JX/3/)**

**UPDATE #2**

For the extra space in the left column (if other columns on the right are larger), use:

```
margin-top:-50px; // (Other columns height minus the shorter left column's height.)
```

On the left columns below the one with a shorter height.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SR62P/1/)**

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't push down content if one div is larger. See > http://jsfiddle.net/5g5YU/5/

Comment: @Nate Check this one out :)

Comment: Nice! I think you got it! Let me play with it a little bit, make sure.

Comment: Okay, I found a problem :/ If the left column has elements that are shorter than their matching elements in the right column, it creates row breaks > http://jsfiddle.net/SR62P/

Comment: Updated answer :) Only way that I think it is possible!

Comment: I'm going to keep trying at this for a little, but if I can't find anything I'll select your answer, as it's the closest.

Comment: Yea, I tried for about 30 minutes before posting that workaround :) Quite honestly, why make the left column shorter.

Comment: If someone can get an answer that is closer than this I would love to see it, but as far as I understand due to the limitations of HTML and CSS this is as close as we're going to get. Also A damn clever method of accomplishing this imho.

Comment: Couple last things, I would say... Setting a `min-height` to `.left` will override the height if the height given to one of the `div` is smaller than it. Secondly, `position:absolute` on `.right` helps get rid of the spacing but doesn't display the other `divs` on the right.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) and create your "grid" like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- left column -->
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
      <!-- right column -->
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
</div>
```

With Bootstrap you can specify different layout for various device sizes by just adding some CSS classes. For example if you want to have two columns in large screens and just one in mobile you can add classes like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

      <!-- left column in medium screens and up -->
      <!-- just one column in small screens -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

      </div>
      <!-- right column in medium screens and up -->
      <!-- just one column in small screens -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">

      </div>
</div>
```

**DEMO:**
http://www.bootply.com/f1zspwlokR

Comment: OP wants the two columns to mix when in mobile so having the two separate containers won't work. He wants the mobile column to be left1 - right1 - left2 - right2 - left3 - right3 not left1 - left2 - left3 -right1 - right2 - right3

Comment: This question is specifically about if columns of multiple elements can be created without container elements. I like bootstrap, I take inspiration from a lot of concepts in it, but it isn't doing anything in your example that I can't do quickly and easily without it.

Comment: @JamesG. Ok, i see.. can't just figure out why try to make things complicated when things can be done easier way.